# No User matches a given query Django

Tags: django

While trying to display post-detail template in a blog app, I get an error `No User matches a given query`. In my models I am inheriting from User model. What seems the problem?

```
# Third party imports.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    """
        Creates Model for a post in the database.
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """
            A string representation of the post model.
        """
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
            Creates the absolute url for a particular post.
        """
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    """
        View for a post's details
    """
    model = Post
    template_name ='blog/post_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3


    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

urls.py:

```
# Third party imports.
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView,
)

# Local application imports.
from . import views

# Specifies the app's name.
app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='home'),  # url for post list.
    path('user/<str:username>/',
         UserPostListView.as_view(),
         name='user-posts'),  # url for specific user post.
    path('post/<int:pk>/',
         PostDetailView.as_view(),
         name='post-detail'),  # url for post detail.
    path('post/new/',
         PostCreateView.as_view(),
         name='post-create'),  # url to create new post.
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/',
         PostUpdateView.as_view(),
         name='post-update'),  # url to update post.
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/',
         PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),  # url to delete post.
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),  # url for about page.
]
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block crumb %}
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="post-preview">
<a href="{% url 'blog:post-detail' post.id %}">
<h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}   </h2>
<h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.sub_title }}  </h3>
</a>

<p class="post-meta" style="font-weight: 300;"> Posted by 
  <a class="text-muted">{{post.author}} on {{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</a>
  
</p>

</div>
<hr class="my-4" />
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img"
         src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2"
           href="{% url 'blog:user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}
        </a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        {% if object.author == user %}
          <div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"
               href="{% url 'blog:post-update' object.id %}">Update
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"
               href="{% url 'blog:post-delete' object.id %}">Delete
            </a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes about things that are wrong that aren't directly related to the error you're getting.

- You're using a `DetailView` (which shows the details for a single object) where it looks like you want a `ListView` (to list an user's posts).

  - Your `context_object_name` is in plural, which implies you do want a list of things.
  - `paginate_by` has no effect in `DetailView`s, since a single-object view couldn't be paginated.
- Your view refers to a `blog/post_detail.html`, while you've pasted in a `home.html`. Which one is it?
- You say "In my models I am inheriting from User model.", but it looks like you're not importing a custom User model, but the default `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. If you really *are* using a custom user model that inherits from BaseUser (not User), then that's wrong too.

---

The error itself, I imagine (since you're not supplying us with the traceback), comes from

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

which means you're not passing in an `<username>` in the URL for that view, or the `<username>` you're using is incorrect (and there is no such user). (You're not showing us your `urls.py`, so that's just a guess.)

(A Detail view's URL, in any case, would probably not refer to an username, but the unique identifier of the post.)

---

## EDIT

Following the edit of the original post, the issue is that the `get_queryset()` is simply extraneous (since no filtering by username is required) in that DetailView, so the class can be simplified to:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name ='blog/post_detail.html'
```

Comment: added post_detail.html, urls.py and views.py. Thanks for the thorough review. I intend to navigate from home ( with a list of blog posts) to a particular post_detail of a blog by an author.

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam Thanks for the edits. Added an edit to my answer – I guess you had copy-pasted the list view to the detail view?

Comment: Ah!  That must be the reason. I may have pasted the get_queryset method into DetailView. A million thanks!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped :)